# is there a way to check if a point is inside circle, other than distance between points?

Tags: geometry

Is there a way to check if a point is inside circle, other than distance between points? I am struggling with floating point precision problems. Is there some method to do the same test, but with more precision? The usual method uses square root...

Comment: The best way (and usual way) to do this is answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/481144/equation-for-testing-if-a-point-is-inside-a-circle Note, there is no square root.

Comment: I see I don't have to compute the distance to center using square root and then compare it to radius, but just have to insert the coordinates to the equation. IF it works, I will use it. thanks

Comment: Can you tell us more about your floating point precision problems? That sounds like the real root problem here. A within-circle check is inherently a distance check (even if we use squared distance as in the comment above) so if you lack precise distance measurements then any way of phrasing the test will tend to run into similar problems.

Comment: it is a nightmare! I am coding the routines to check if my character is hitting the walls and then computing the corrected movement. And there Is not a way for me to deal with floating point precision errors. Even if the error is less than .0000000000000000000000000001, it gives me problems. It will be more stable with smaller epsilon but it will never be glitches proof. That's why I had to avoid using epsilon at all. I mean, my code is independent of floating point precision issues. for now I managed it, but next I have to introduce circles to the setup and this will bring me more headaches..

Comment: It might be useful if you talked a little about the *kind* of problems you get. Don't tell us what you think the cause is, tell us what the problems are, because if even that degree of precision error is bad, you may be doing something wrong elsewhere.

Comment: I have not the fault if the machine can't do math. And I can't solve it easily, because if the precision is 0.000...0001 there always will be a rare case where the real world result is 0.000...00005 and a glitch will happen.

Comment: This sounds a lot like you're overcomplicating things. If done right, you shouldn't even need flashing point numbers. This is a great resource for inspiration: http://info.sonicretro.org/SPG:Solid_Tiles

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no real way around using the distance. There's always *some* error margin you have to accept and I don't think it will get any better using some more complex algorithm.

You can skip the square root though:

```
is_inside = (delta_x * delta_x + delta_y * delta_y) < (radius * radius)
```

If this isn't precise enough for you, you can try multiplying all values by 100 first (or whatever you need to make them bigger than 1), but I think your problem is really somewhere else.

Comment: I tried to avoid the precision issues changing the logic of my code. for straight lines, I managed it. But I have to add circles and even if lately I manage to avoid precision errors with circles too, having an algorithm that uses less computations like the one you are showing is always good for me.
Why I have to multiply by 100? I divided by 1000 in order to get all values below 1. As far as I know, the best precision of floating point numbers below 1. Am I wrong about it?

Comment: @NIki It's implementation specific, but basically the further away from the decimal point (or more precise, the floating point) the less accurate it is. By dividing you might actually introduce more error (due to lack of precision). Think of integer division. You just don't lose all decimals. But this also depends on numbers. 5000 should be as accurate as 5. But if the error margin is 0.005, using 5 has the bigger deviation.

Comment: http://jasss.soc.surrey.ac.uk/9/4/4/fig1.jpg
this image shows that toward zero we have greater precision. I am almost sure, but you made me doubt it a little bit. Just to be totally sure I will ask in Assembly programing forums. people there should know it.

Comment: Even though it is true, that there is more floting point number closer to zero, dividing will only make it worse, because you can only lose information by doing so.

Comment: @Sopel Yes, but by doing so you might also get the values close enough to match. It's very situational though.